# Table extraction using rvest from a website with selection

Tags: r, checkbox, rvest

I am trying to get a table from this page here: http://www.kase.kz/en/ticker/index
However, I will have to select a type of instruments before I go further. I would like to select the following two:  "National Bank of the Republic of Kazakhstan" and "Ministry of Finance of the Republic of Kazakhstan".

I have tried the following code:

```
library(rvest)
p <- url %>%
read_html() %>%
html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="pl1_11"]/table') %>%
html_table()
```

and I am getting:

```
list()
```

Any suggestions?

UPDATE

This code seems to work, but its giving the output in text form

```
url <- "http://www.kase.kz/en/ticker/index"
p <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//td') %>%
  html_text()
p
```

Comment: I think it's loading data with jQuery, which means you'd need RSelenium to run the JavaScript before you could scrape.

Comment: if I return text instead of table, it seems to work ... do you still think that I need RSelenium?

Comment: Weird, you're right. The tables themselves don't have any distinguishing attributes, so I was looking inside of the `div`s they appear in as rendered by a browser, but they're empty when scraped. Just looking for `table`s works, though, so apparently the JavaScript is just shifting around the DOM between what you scrape and what a browser renders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the DOM of the scraped HTML, the tables are there—just not where they are when you view the page in a browser. Thus, with a little investigation, you can figure out some selectors:

```r
library(rvest)

p <- "http://www.kase.kz/en/ticker/index" %>% read_html()

nat_bank <- p %>% html_node('#pl1_10 + h2 + table') %>% html_table()

head(nat_bank)
#>          Code                                         Issuer  NIN or ISIN
#> 1 NTK007_1911 SI National Bank of the Republic of Kazakhstan KZW1KD079112
#> 2 NTK007_1914 SI National Bank of the Republic of Kazakhstan KZW1KD079146
#> 3 NTK007_1915 SI National Bank of the Republic of Kazakhstan KZW1KD079153
#> 4 NTK008_1913 SI National Bank of the Republic of Kazakhstan KZW1KD089137
#> 5 NTK028_1896 SI National Bank of the Republic of Kazakhstan KZW1KD288960
#> 6 NTK028_1903 SI National Bank of the Republic of Kazakhstan KZW1KD289034
#>             Type
#> 1 discount notes
#> 2 discount notes
#> 3 discount notes
#> 4 discount notes
#> 5 discount notes
#> 6 discount notes

min_of_fin <- p %>% html_node('#pl1_11 + h2 + table') %>% html_table()

head(min_of_fin)
#>          Code                                                Issuer
#> 1  KZ_05_2410 The Ministry of Finance of the Republic of Kazakhstan
#> 2  KZ_06_4410 The Ministry of Finance of the Republic of Kazakhstan
#> 3 MOM024_0085 The Ministry of Finance of the Republic of Kazakhstan
#> 4 MOM036_0087 The Ministry of Finance of the Republic of Kazakhstan
#> 5 MOM036_0088 The Ministry of Finance of the Republic of Kazakhstan
#> 6 MOM036_0089 The Ministry of Finance of the Republic of Kazakhstan
#>                NIN or ISIN      Type
#> 1 XS1120709669US486661AE13 eurobonds
#> 2 XS1120709826US486661AF87 eurobonds
#> 3             KZK2KY020859    МЕОКАМ
#> 4             KZK2KY030871    MEOKAM
#> 5             KZK2KY030882    MEOKAM
#> 6             KZK2KY030890    МЕОКАМ
```

...or just grab *all* the tables and figure out what you need later:

```r
df_list <- p %>% html_nodes('table') %>% html_table(fill = TRUE)

df_list[[12]] %>% head()
#>          Code                                         Issuer  NIN or ISIN
#> 1 NTK007_1911 SI National Bank of the Republic of Kazakhstan KZW1KD079112
#> 2 NTK007_1914 SI National Bank of the Republic of Kazakhstan KZW1KD079146
#> 3 NTK007_1915 SI National Bank of the Republic of Kazakhstan KZW1KD079153
#> 4 NTK008_1913 SI National Bank of the Republic of Kazakhstan KZW1KD089137
#> 5 NTK028_1896 SI National Bank of the Republic of Kazakhstan KZW1KD288960
#> 6 NTK028_1903 SI National Bank of the Republic of Kazakhstan KZW1KD289034
#>             Type
#> 1 discount notes
#> 2 discount notes
#> 3 discount notes
#> 4 discount notes
#> 5 discount notes
#> 6 discount notes
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you please explain the way you figured out + h2 + table? Because when I use SelectorGadget, it just gives #pl1_10 or #pl1_11.

Comment: The problem is the page on the web is useless for selectors, as the tags are arranged differently in what you scrape. Unfortunately RStudio doesn't have a great XML/HTML viewer AFAIK ([htmltidy](https://hrbrmstr.github.io/htmltidy/) has an `html_view` function, but it doesn't compare to a browser), but a not-too-horrible workaround is to simply write out the scraped HTML with `write_html(p, 'p.html')` and open it with a browser: `browseURL('p.html')`, where you can inspect the DOM easily and use SelectorGadget if you like.

Comment: There you can see everything was unnested to direct children of `body`, so the `h2` and `table` now follow the `div` that contained them. Since the `div` is the only thing with a useful ID, you can write the selector relative to it, starting with the ID `#pl1_10`, looking for the `h2` directly following it (`+ h2`) and the `table` following _that_ (`+ table`), which is the node you want. For further explanation of CSS selectors, see [the tutorial linked in `?html_nodes`](https://flukeout.github.io/).

Answer (score 0):

Playing around, I came across XML package, which also got the work done:

```
library(XML)
x = readHTMLTable('http://www.kase.kz/en/ticker/index')
Nat_Bank = x[[12]]
MF = x[[13]]
```